# "Open with Explorer" credential problem

Tags: 2010, permissions

When connected as System Account (maximum permissions possible) I'm able to do whatever I want with all the document lists in my site. When clicking an "Open with Explorer", it opens an explorer window in the right place, as expected, but I get an authorization error from Explorer whenever I try to create a new folder, copy some file etc.

Any help?

Comment: 1) What happens if you just use a "normal" user account?
2) Tell us a bit about what you are doing, and how! Like: Is your SP2010 a farm deployment? Single server? Dev-installation on Win7? How are you accessing the site -through web browser of your local machine or directly from the server? Are you, the SP server and everything else in the same domain? Does it happen on every site -or just one? Are you local administrator on your machine and the SP server?

Answer (score 1):

Without more information as @AlexPoint listed it is hard to give direction.  Explorer View piece is actually pretty complicated.

MS Released a whitepaper a while back for 2007.  It may assist you with your efforts.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=C523AC7A-5724-48BE-B973-641E805588F4&displaylang=en